# Include config for subdirectory in Nginx

Tags: php, drupal, nginx

For example, I have a webserver for testing.

Now I put Drupal 8 in a Subdirectory.

The server config in Nginx is OK for plain php files, but Drupal needs another config because of URL scheme.

My goal is something like this:

normal.cfg

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name _;

   location (phpfiles) {
      pass to PHPFPM;
   }
}
```

drupal_test.cfg

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name _;

   location /drupal/(phpfiles) {
      do_some_magic
      pass to PHPFPM;
   }
}
```

But then Nginx complains about ignoring duplicated `server_name`.

So, how can I include a specific (separated file) configuration for a given subdirectory of a given `server_name` that I can later delete without much problems? This is because I don't want to mess up the main config.

Answer (score 0):

the probably most common way of doing this is to include a separate file for every virtual server. you can either include a specific file with

```
include /path/of/configfile;
```

or choose the common way by using a wildcard:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

in both cases you have to put this line in the http direcitve of your nginx config file.

Comment: Yes but it is the same virtualserver, just special config for one subdirectory but I don't want to mess up the main config, just plug this special dir config until it is no more needed